Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt2}{-\sqrt[3] {4}+7}$ over $\mathbb Q$.
I need to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt2}{-\sqrt[3] {4}+7}$ over $\mathbb Q$ to determine $[E:\mathbb Q(\alpha)]$ where $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt 3)$.
If I put the denumerator to left side: $(-\sqrt[3] {4}+7)x=\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt2$ (instead $\alpha$ write $x$), my following attempt  was taking third power of both sides but operations are getting nasty. Is there a easier way to find minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?
On the other hand, it is clear that $(\sqrt[3] 2)^2=\sqrt[3]4$. Here is my claim: $\mathbb Q\biggl (\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt2}{-\sqrt[3] {4}+7} \bigg)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt2)$.
$\supseteq$ part is obvious but I couldn't show other way around.

I assume you meant $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}$ in the definition of $E?$

I think you mixed up $\supseteq$ and $\subseteq$.

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]2).$

More generally, you can prove $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[m]D,\sqrt[n]D)\cong\mathbb Q(\sqrt[\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)]D).$$

You all are totally right.

Let $\beta = \sqrt[6]{2}$.  $\sqrt[3]{2} = \beta^2$, $\sqrt{2} = \beta^3$, and $\sqrt[3]{4} = \beta^4$, so:
$$\alpha=\dfrac{\beta^2+3\beta^3}{-\beta^4+7}$$
$$\alpha(-\beta^4+7)=\beta^2+3\beta^3$$
$$\alpha\beta^4+3\beta^3+\beta^2-7\alpha=0 \tag{1}$$
Now, let's repeatedly multiply this equation by $\beta$.
$$\alpha\beta^5+3\beta^4+\beta^3-7\alpha\beta=0 \tag{2}$$
$$\alpha\beta^6+3\beta^5+\beta^4-7\alpha\beta^2=0$$
But $\beta^6 = 2$, so this is equivalent to:
$$3\beta^5+\beta^4-7\alpha\beta^2+2\alpha=0 \tag{3}$$
Doing the “Multiply by $\beta$ and replace $\beta^6 = 2$” thing three more times gives:
$$\beta^5-7\alpha\beta^3+2\alpha\beta+6=0 \tag{4}$$
$$-7\alpha\beta^4+2\alpha\beta^2+6\beta+2=0 \tag{5}$$
$$-7\alpha\beta^5+2\alpha\beta^3+6\beta^2+2\beta=0 \tag{6}$$
Or, combining equations (1) through (6) in matrix form,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 && \alpha && 3 && 1 && 0 && -7\alpha \\
\alpha && 3 && 1 && 0 && -7\alpha && 0 \\
3 && 1 && 0 && -7\alpha && 0 && 2\alpha \\
1 && 0 && -7\alpha && 0 && 2\alpha && 6 \\
0 && -7\alpha && 0 && 2\alpha && 6 && 2 \\
-7\alpha && 0 && 2\alpha && 6 && 2 && 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta^5 \\
\beta^4 \\
\beta^3 \\
\beta^2 \\
\beta \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
= 0$$
Note that the $6 \times 6$ matrix has an eigenvalue of $0$.  Which means its determinant is zero.  Evaluating this determinant (with a CAS because I'm lazy) gives:
$$\boxed{-114921 \alpha^6 + 28476 \alpha^5 + 130914 \alpha^4 + 1356 \alpha^3 - 47148 \alpha^2 - 2376 \alpha + 5828 = 0}$$
You can numerically verify that the given $\alpha \approx 1.0166209966498758$ satisfies this equation.  Proof that this is the minimal polynomial to do so is left as an exercise for the reader.
